# How can I upload files to Office365 SharePoint with vb or c# class?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, office365

New to office 365. I have done uploading code in both c# and powershell. I was wondering if there is already ready-made code that can upload a local file to office 365 sharepoint.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SharePoint Online is offering various APIs to deal with SharePoint and the data stored within SharePoint Online (SPO).

You can easily add new data to SharePoint using RESTful API (ListData.svc) from any programming language. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff521587.aspx

Comment: As of now the link is outdated - SP2010